# How to update divider to the right place in a RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I wrote the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/full_name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/avatar"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/avatar"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/blackColor"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <!-- Divider -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It's the item layout of the RecyclerView. Basicly it creates the following layout:

```
[avatar] [name]
---------------------
[avatar] [name]
---------------------
[avatar] [name]
```

The Java code:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // Code
        // Set avatar

        // Set name
        holder.fullname.setText((CharSequence) name);

        // Set visible/invisible divider
        if (position < getItemCount() - 1) {
            holder.viewDivider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.viewDivider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the divider is being set on top of the `ImageView` and the `TextView` and not on the bottom of each block. I think that I understand why it happens - the divider is already there so when I set `ImageView` and `TextView` dynamically, the divider is not being rendered to the right place. Or maybe it's related to `android:layout_centerVertical`? How should I fix it?

Also, In the activity which sets the adapter I call:

```
holder.users.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.activity));
```

Is it ok that I call `LinearLayoutManager` when the layout (of the item) is `RelativeLayout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!-- Divider -->
<View
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/avatar"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"  <-- REMOVE THIS LINE :)
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should enclose your image and textview in a layout preferably in a relative layout and then take a view and below that layout like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:id="@+id/rlLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/full_name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/avatar"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/avatar"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Test String"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Divider -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rlLayout"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```